# How to cd into the first directory after sorting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ls, cd

I have a folder in which there are directories

```
ABC_1
ABC_2
ABC_3
ABC_4
ABC_5
Test
XYZ
```

I want to sort them by date,remove the directories which do not contain ABC in their name and cd into the first directory.

I tried

```
cd $(/bin/ls -t1 | head -n 1)
```

This is not working.
Any help would be much appreciated
  Thanks.

Comment: "Not working" how? You should explain what the current behavior is...

Comment: I get an error directory_name: Not a directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will list **only** directories and filter out any folder that does not start with ABC_:

```
cd "$(ls -t1 -d */ |grep  "^ABC_" |head -n1)"
```

**UPDATE:**

You actually do not need *grep*

```
cd "$(ls -t1 -d ABC_*/ | head -n1)"
```

Comment: `ls` can be a bit risky (see [why you shouldn't use the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). Would it be an option of using Zsh instead of Bash? With Zsh, the command would be `cd *(D[1])`. The `D` picks only the directories, the wildcard (*) sorts them alphabetically, and `[1]` takes the first one.

Comment: @user1934428 I am aware of the pitfalls and normally I would avoid `cd`-ing into a directory from a script in the first place. I would probably use a combination of `find`, `stat` and `sort`. However, OP did not specify what his ultimate goal is which makes it hard to guess a better solution. Furthermore, the output has to be sorted according to modification time (`ls -t`) and not alphabetically.

Comment: If you need to chdir into the newest one based on modification time, you can do it with **zsh** using `setopt extendedglob` and then `cd *(#q/om[-1])`. See the section with the heading *Glob Qualifiers* in the zsh man-page.

Comment: (Just for completeness: I just noticed that I made a typing mistake in my previous comment. For getting the first one in alphabetical order, the correct pattern would be `*(/[1])` and not `*(D[1])`. The `/` picks directories, while the `D` would just turn on matching for files/directories, where the name starts with a period.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd "$(/bin/ls -t1 | grep ABC | head -n 1)"
```

Comment: This command is not showing my ABC directories and showing the other directories

Comment: @MohitArora: Sorry I had `grep -v` when I should have just had `grep` because I misread your question.  I fixed it now.

Comment: What about `/bin/ls/*ABC*` then? (I also would've assumed `grep -v` from the question).

Comment: @fedorqui: The problem with `ls *` solutions is that they will fail if there are lots of matches, because the command line will become too long.  So I don't do that unless I'm sure the matches are few.

Comment: Well, that is rare, but yes, in general [parsing ls is evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) : )

Answer (score 0):

The poster is wanting the first result after the list not the first result according to modification time so the "-t" option is not needed.

You also have to make sure that you're pulling just directories and not files.

This will do what you want:

```
cd $(ls -d [^ABC]*/ | head -n 1)
```

- $() run command
- ls -d search for directories
- [^ABC]*/ do not include any directories that start with ABC*
- head -n 1 return the first entry
- cd change to the directory